# Objects getting logged twice in the console , while inspect and cant add take the data and store in the state "movie"

Tags: reactjs, web-services

**This is my code and i cant take the data movie.title**
Objects getting logged twice in the console , while inspect and cant add take the data and store in the state "movie"
i couldn't find any solution .[The console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUhqT.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from "../../axios"
import {API_KEY} from "../../Constants/constants"

import "./Banner.css"

function Banner() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState()
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(`trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`).then((Response)=>{
      console.log(Response.data.results[0]);
      setMovie(Response.data.results[0])

    })

  },[])

   

  return (
    <div className="banner">
        <div className="content">
           ***<h1>{movie.title}</h1>***
             <div className="banner-buttons">
                <button className="button">Play</button>
                <button className="button">More-info</button>

           </div>
           <h1 className="description">Part 4 (also referred to as the second part of season 2) Of Netflix's Money Heist consists of 8 episodes. It was released on April 3, 2020. Money Heist Part</h1>
           </div>
           <div className="fade-bottom"></div>







    </div>
  )
}

export default Banner


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWAQl.png
```